# Laravel get users by state using city id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

I have `users` table where has `city_id` and each city in `cities` table has `state_id`. How I can get users using `city_id` from any state?

Here is my code:

```
$users = User::role('company')
            ->when((int) $state, function ($query, $state) {
                // here query
            })
            ->when((int) $city, function ($query, $city) {
                return $query->where('city_id', $city);
            })
            ->get();
```

**I tried:**

```
$users = User::role('company')
            ->when((int) $state, function ($query, $state) {
                $cities = City::where('state_id', $state)
                            ->pluck('id')
                            ->toArray();
                return $query->whereIn('city_id', $cities);
            })
            ->when((int) $city, function ($query, $city) {
                return $query->where('city_id', $city);
            })
            ->get();
```

It's work but how to do this query correctly without make new query with `City` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you built the relation between user and city? it should be something like:

```
 public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'city_id');
    }
```

you can use that relation to get users [where has](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) a city that belongs to that state:

```
$users = User::role('company')
            ->when((int) $state, function ($query)use ($state) {
                return $query->whereHas('city',function ($query)use ($state){
                    $query->where('state_id',$state);
                });
            })
            ->when((int) $city, function ($query)use($city) {
                return $query->where('city_id', $city);
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: hi @Andreas Hunter , thank for editing, anyway the inline function works fine with or without return, but it's clearer with return like your edit did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel HasManyThough

given that you have a state, each state has many cities, each city has many users

then in the state model, you can add this function

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, City::class);
}
```

this function will return all the users in a given state

example:

```
$state = State::first();
$users = $state->users;
```

for further info read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)